# Upgrade DNN Verion 7

Tags: dotnetnuke-6

I have a site running in DNN 6.0 . I upgrade the DNN verion 7. After Upgrade the Design  the site is totally  messup  can any one give me the idea  how to Update the DNN to verion  7.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's not necessary that the upgrade went wrong. 
Maybe some of the modules you are using are incompatible with DNN7 or you have changed some of the core pages or styles.

It's hard to give a more precise answer since 'totally messed up' doesn't really say what's the problem

Answer (score 0):

Posting the stack trace or error message would help a lot if you want a useful answer.

Often 'totally messed up' is due to a dll version issue.

On a side note, I hope that you have backed up both the database and website files before you upgraded the site. If you have added 3rd party modules, check their compatibility with DNN 7.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, you need to basically update the skins to use Gravity (or some other half-decent skin besides DarkKnight) - right now, it is probably using the old DarkKnight skin (I would guess) and I've seen a lot of issues trying to use DarkKnight in DNN 7.x.x.

Try this:

1.) Admin\Site Settings\Basic Settings\Appearance

2.) Set Site Theme\Container and Edit Theme\Container to Gravity (anything but DarkKnight)

3.) Host\Host Settings\Basic Settings\Appearnace

4.) Set Host Theme\Container and Edit Theme Container to Gravity (anything but DarkKnight)